# Update Private Ethereum node

Tags: contract-development, private

Now suppose I created my private blockchain using ethereum over any cloud, created dapps over it and created my own crypto over that. Now if ethereum update consensus to POS from POW I want my private blockchain to do same.

Is it possible  to update the private blockchain with all new updates of ethereum without breaking existing system running on a private blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

In previous forks it was possible to upgrade private geth blockchains to the new features without modifying the source code.

Since PoS code is not ready yet we can only speculate that it might be possible to upgrade. Eth 2.0 will have many other features like sharding that makes future upgrades harder.